# Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value AVAUDIO Player SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, avaudioplayer

I am currently downloading an m4a file from firebase and trying to play the file with AVAudio Player.

How the system works

1. Get path of downloaded file as String

`let pathForAudio: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "path") ?? "There is no path for the audio"`

2. Convert to URL

`let url = URL(string: pathForAudio)`

3. Pass URL into AVAUDIOPLAYER Function

`soundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)`

When doing             soundPlayer.play()  I get "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

I have seen this problem on Stack Before and they just enable permissions on a static file. Here the file path always changes so I cannot perform their solution.

Any help is much appreciated, let me know if you need other code blocks. Thanks so much!

Comment: Is it a path “/some/thing” or a URI “file://some/thing” . If it’s the former you need URL(path: url)

Answer (score 0):

You define your path this way:

```
let pathForAudio: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "path") ?? "There is no path for the audio"
```

This could result in:

1. A valid file path stored in `UserDefaults`
2. An invalid file path stored in `UserDefaults`
3. Nothing stored in `UserDefaults`, which would then cause it to be `"There is no path for the audio"`

Unless you get scenario #1, then your next call (`let url = URL(string: pathForAudio)`) will fail, returning a `nil` value (which is what's happening right now.  Then, upon calling `try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)`, because you're force unwrapping with `!`, you'll have a crash because you have a `nil` value that you're telling the system *isn't* nil by using `!`

In short, you need to put a valid path into `UserDefaults` in order for this system to work.

I'd also do some error checking along the way. Something like:

```
guard let pathForAudio = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "path") else {
  //handle the fact that there wasn't a path
  return
}

guard let url = URL(string: pathForAudio) else {
  //handle the fact that a URL couldn't be made from the string (ie, invalid path
  return
}

//see if the file exists
guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pathForAudio) else {
  //handle no file
  return
}

do {
  soundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url) //notice there's now no !
} catch {
  //handle error
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: I am confident that the UserDefault is populated. Prior to passing in the string I used a print statement and the string matches what I want. Could this be a permissions issue with Xcode or something?         print(url!, "URL to Setup Player") is not nil when I run in console

Comment: Is the path a local resource? What is the value when you print it? Anything in your bundle or app document folder you should have access to, but you don't necessarily have access to anything else.

Comment: Have you visited that directory in Finder to make sure there's really a file there? Also, I updated my answer with a check for whether the file exists, using FileManager

Comment: Thank you it was a file path error, and a permissions issue.